# Setting up eclipse for maya 2013

Tags: python, eclipse, maya

I followed this instructions:

http://www.luma-pictures.com/tools/pymel/docs/1.0/eclipse.html

Also have read the Maya's documentation:

http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/files/Python_Python_from_an_external_interpreter.htm#

And now I can successfully import and initialize Maya Standalone and
Cmds module.

BUT, as I try to code something like 'cmds.polyCube()', first I don't have any
auto completion and secondly Eclipse returns with an error saying that cmds module
Doesn't has any variable that named polyCube() etc....
Here is my exact procedure which I use to import and initialize maya inside Eclipse:

```
import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize()

import maya
from maya import cmds

cmds.polyCube(n='cuby_01')
cmds.select('cuby_01')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you followed this step from the pymel eclipse docs:

> Click the “New Folder” button again, and add the site-packages directory you removed earlier. We did this in order to ensure that the
>   stub maya package is found before the real maya package. When you’re
>   done, the main site-packages directory should be somewhere below the
>   extras/completion/py folder you just added.

That is the important part for adding the stubs to your custom interpreter. In the end you should have a mayapy interpreter set up, with this added site-packages location. And also, make sure when you create a new pydev project, that you go into its specific properties and set the python interpreter to the mayapy that you set up. Otherwise you could still possibly be using the default python interp.

Comment: I did all of the steps above again, even uninstalled java and eclipse, then reconfigured the eclipse IDE but still I am having problems, I don't know why this should happen! I've downloaded the latest version of pymel and installed it manually as the documentation says but this way I've got other problems :(

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little explanation here, how to add a mayapay interpreter here:
[Eclipse environment for Maya's python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841190/eclipse-environment-for-mayas-python-modules/13576949#13576949)

I'm pretty sure is this one your problem.

give a look and if you have any question don't hesitate to ask here again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.creativecrash.com/tutorials/using-eclipse-as-a-maya-ide  (the most relevant portion is available on the 'page 2' tab in the linked page).  Basically, you need to point Eclipse's 'predefined' at the  /devkit/other/pymel/extras/completion/pypredef

[image: pypredef]

Your sample should work correctly as long as (a) you're using a 2.6 interpreter and (b) you've got the maya python directory in your eclipse PYTHONPATH:

[image]
  Its usually easiest to configure eclipse to use /bin/mayapy.exe as the intepreter for maya.  You might find it easier to use

```
import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize()
import maya.cmds as cmds
pc = cmds.polyCube()
```

the cmds module imports as empty UNLESS you've already initialized maya.standalone - your sample shows that but perhaps you got that error in an earlier run without standalone.initialize()?