# Change Python version in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to change the version of python within maya.  Specifically, I want maya (maya 2013) script editor to use python2.7 and all other packages/modules attached to that version. I also want to be able to import pymel and maya from eclipse.

I've tried following this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656593/how-do-i-change-the-python-version-in-maya-2013/14706115#14706115) but no luck. Maya still points to its default version.

From python, i try to import pymel with

```
import pymel.core as pm
```

and I get an error that reads

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File
 "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymel/core/__init__.py",
 line 6, in <module>
    import pymel.versions as _versions   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymel/versions.py",
 line 12, in <module>
    from maya.OpenMaya import MGlobal  as _MGlobal ImportError: Bad magic number in
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/maya/OpenMaya.pyc
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are able to rebuild the pyc files (easiest way is to delete them and then import them again, provided you have the corresponding py files in the same location), that will probably clear up the magic number error.

Comment: this may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841190/eclipse-environment-for-mayas-python-modules

Comment: [This](http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/tutorials/using-tools-scripts/c/using-eclipse-as-a-maya-ide) is a really nice plug-in and tutorial for using Eclipse as a Maya IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method described in your link does work, however you have to point Python to to Maya's Python's DLLs and site-packages folder via the global `PYTHONPATH` variable. I successfully changed it to 2.7 and imported PyMEL by setting the following.

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH;C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013\Python\DLLs;C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013\Python\Lib\site-packages
```

Just tailor that for Linux or Mac, whichever, and it should do the trick. Not much is actually needed except for assigning a `PYTHONHOME` var to the version of Python you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Add maya python paths in your python IDE

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013\Python\DLLs

C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013\Python\Lib\site-packages
```

this works for me in [PyCharm Python IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)